# Vim substitute - encase `\ref{eq:x}` with brackets

Tags: regex, vim

I have a latex document which has a bunch of strings of the form

```
Eq.~\ref{eq:x}
```

where `x` is in general a different string for each occurrence. I want to replace the above with

```
Eq.~(\ref{eq:x})
```

I can match some of the occurrences searching with `/\\ref{eq:.*\}` but this doesn't work if you have something like

```
blah Eq.~\ref{eq:x} something something \cite{this}
```

Note that I don't want to replace `\ref{eq:` with a latex macro which handles the brackets internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is a greedy quantifier that will match as many characters as possible. So, if you have several `}` on the line, `.*}` will match every character up to the last `}` on the line.

You should use a non-greedy quantifier instead:

```
/\\ref{eq:.\{-}\}
```

See `:help \{`.

Comment: Thanks. How can I substitute it with the required text? e.g. `:%s//\\ref{eq:.\{-}\}/(\\ref{eq:.\{-}\})/g` obviously won't work

Comment: So, I _completely_ forgot about the `\eqref` command... In any case this was useful.

Comment: Despite the title, your question is strictly limited to the search, not the replacement. Anyway, you can use `&` in the replacement part to refer to the whole match so, to enclose the match between parentheses, you would do `:s/foo/(&)/g`.